# Cutting text to fit it in a box(tooltip)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create my own tooltip for a program that I'm doing and I want the text of the tooltip to fit into a box where the maximum letters per line is fixed (say 12).

For example, consider the following string:

```
String example = "Hello my name is Martin"; //(23 letters)
```

So now I want to fit this text into a box.

Correctly formatted text for this string would look like this:

> line 1: "Hello my"
>
> line 2: "name is"
>
> line 3: "Martin"

I really don't know how I can work this out. One of the things I think of is to split the input string after each `" "`, like:

```
String[] splittedExample = example.split("\\s+");
```

But then I will need an algorithm for checking how much of these array contents can be written in a line till a max of 12 is reached.

I'm open for any other solutions as well.

It would be great if anyone would know how I could do this. Also, I want these lines to be stored in a String Array.

Thanks

Comment: Well you could split after two words since your expected output has two words each..

Comment: nope that was just an example string if 2 words together have mor than 12 letters the whole concept would fail

Comment: Oh sorry didn't read the 12 character limit..

Comment: What if there's a word in your string loger than 12 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own method to do that:

```
public static String getLimitedString(String str, int len){
    StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();             
    while(str.length() > 0){
        if(str.length() < len){
            txt.append(str.trim());
            str = "";
        }           
        else if(str.charAt(len) == ' '){
            txt.append(str.substring(0, len+1).trim() + "\n");
            str = str.substring(len+1);
        }                   
        else{
            txt.append(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(' ', len)).trim() + "\n");
            str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(' ', len));
        }   
    }
    return txt.toString();      
}
```

**Test:**

```
System.out.println(getLimitedString("Hello my name is Martin", 12));
```

**Output:**

```
Hello my
name is
Martin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function to split & wrap the input string for specified length. In the code below I used `\n` as the separator, you can change it if you want.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /* Input String */
    String input = "Hello my name is Martin";
    String result = wrapString(input, 12);

    /* String Array */
    String[] strArray = result.split("\n");

    /* Print Result */
    System.out.println(result);
}

/**
 * Wrap String Function
 * Arguments: String, Wrap Size
**/
private static String wrapString(String input, int size) {
    /* Create Char Array */
    char[] inpArr = input.toCharArray();
    /* Wrap Logic */
    if (inpArr.length > size) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (temp = size; temp > 0 && inpArr[temp] != ' '; temp--);
        if (temp > 0) {
            /* Left & Right Substrings */
            String left = input.substring(0, temp);
            String right = input.substring(temp + 1);
            /* Return */
            return left + "\n" + wrapString(right, size);
        }
    }
    /* Return */
    return input;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello my
name is
Martin
```